# How do get the different values that takes an attribute with a django query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this Model in django :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like to get the different values that are used in the category attribute.

For example, if we consider this db :

```
Post(title = "title 1", category="foo")
Post(title = "title 2", category="bar")
Post(title = "title 3", category="foo")
```

the query should give me ("foo", "bar")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and [`values_list()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list-fields):

```
Post.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct();
```

Comment: thanks!

here is fore reference the django doc page http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct